# How to create a sequence of repeating numbers in a column based on a starting number?

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

treatment <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
desired <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4)

df_treatment <- tibble(treatment, desired)

df <- df_treatment %>% 
  mutate(date = seq(as_date("2016-01-01"), as_date("2016-01-15") , by= "day"))
```

My goal is to get the `desired` column in the `df` tibble. Of course, I would like to get this programmatically. In addition, I would like to be flexible with the number of times each number is repeating. For instance, I may want to change the numbers to repeating 4 times instead of 3.

While this may seem like a strange question, I am trying to find the best way to get a "time past/to treatment" column in a larger data set. My idea right now is to create a sequence of numbers starting with the date the treatment starts. Each unique number in the `desired` column would be a bin, while the number of times each unique number repeats would be the number of observation in each bin.

For some reason, when I try to create something like this, I can't seem to get the numbers to start in the correct place:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(desired_attempt = ifelse(date >= as_date("2016-01-05"), rep(1:4, each = 3), 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(treatment_started = date >= "2016-01-03") %>% 
  mutate(desired_attempt = if (first(treatment_started)) rep(1:1e3, each = 3, length.out = n()) else 0)
```

```
# A tibble: 15 × 5
# Groups:   treatment_started [2]
   treatment desired date       treatment_started desired_attempt
       <dbl>   <dbl> <date>     <lgl>                       <dbl>
 1         0       0 2016-01-01 FALSE                           0
 2         0       0 2016-01-02 FALSE                           0
 3         0       0 2016-01-03 TRUE                            1
 4         0       0 2016-01-04 TRUE                            1
 5         1       1 2016-01-05 TRUE                            1
 6         0       1 2016-01-06 TRUE                            2
 7         0       1 2016-01-07 TRUE                            2
 8         0       2 2016-01-08 TRUE                            2
 9         0       2 2016-01-09 TRUE                            3
10         0       2 2016-01-10 TRUE                            3
11         0       3 2016-01-11 TRUE                            3
12         0       3 2016-01-12 TRUE                            4
13         0       3 2016-01-13 TRUE                            4
14         0       4 2016-01-14 TRUE                            4
15         0       4 2016-01-15 TRUE                            5
```

---

Or with base R:

```
df$desired_attempt <- 0
df$desired_attempt[df$date >= "2016-01-03"] <- rep(1:1e3, each = 3, length.out = sum(df$date >= "2016-01-03"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a <- cumsum(treatment)
b <- sum(a)
replace(treatment, a>0, rep(seq_len(b), each=3, length = b))
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4
```